# Mutability of a pandas dataframe in a tuple

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tuples

We all know that any assignment of variables to a DataFrame object in Pandas will only be a reference but not a new instance. However, what if I assign a variable 't' to a tuple that consists of a string and a pandas DataFrame as follows:

```
df=pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
t=('example',df)
```

When I do:

```
new=t[1]
```

is the variable new a reference to the original object 'df' (i.e. mutable and exposed) or it is now referred to a new instance (i.e. df is immutable in this case)?

Thank you.

Comment: `new` is another pointer to the same dataframe that `df` points to.  And that dataframe is mutable.  For example, when I do `new is df` I get `True`.  And `id(new) == id(df)` is also `True`.

Comment: it depends, on my machine `new` is a copy but it maybe a view, also why do you think it's immutable

Comment: Unless you use df.copy(), It will refer back to same dataframe the varaible is assigned to no matter where you store the dataframe.  As @pir said another pointer thats it.

Comment: @Bharathshetty that's not always the case I did `new = new * 2` and `df` isn't modified, it really depends

Comment: @EdChum the example you cited `new = new * 2` I wouldn't expect to alter `df`.  `new * 2` creates a copy and you assign it to `new` which overwrites what was there.  `new.loc[:] = new * 2` would be a different story.

Comment: @pir, I am asking this question in the forum because I thought tuple (similar to the behavior string) that it always gives you a new object unlike list. So I thought if we call a DataFrame in a tuple will create a new object without having the need to do the .copy()

Comment: @EdChum I didn't know it depends on machine too. Thank you. It would be nice to know how it depends. Like how and why it differs from one system to another?

Comment: @piRSquared that's true but it's difficult to capture all the use cases when making an assumption that `new` is always a reference or copy so context matters

Comment: @Bharathshetty I think @piRSquared pointed out that this will create a new object and overwrite, but if you did `new.loc[1,1] = 10` then this would affect the orig df. The point here is that context matters and it becomes ambiguous unless you explicitly take a `copy()`

Comment: In regards to the tuple of mutable objects.  [**See This Question**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9755990/2336654)

Comment: I appreciate the prompt and active responses. While treasuring the great benefit of pandas.DataFrame object, I also find the limitations of it in terms of the ambiguity of its mutability. Can I safely say that it is always a good practice to do a copy() to avoid mutation? In general does doing copy() every time significantly reduce performance of a program?

Comment: @user7786493 I think you are mixing the concepts of mutability, references, and views.  You are using the term mutability but it sounds like you are concerned with altering the contents of a first dataframe when changing the contents of a second dataframe that was created from the first.  If I'm correct, then using `df2 = df1.copy()` is your guaranteed solution.

Comment: Aggregated all queries and responses in a [community wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45865052/4909087). Please feel free to edit.

Comment: @user7786493 Do you have any more questions?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ personally do not recommend `inplace=True` flag

Comment: @Wen Me neither! I only mentioned it for the sake of completeness in my answer.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I suffered a lot from it when it is`chained indexing`:(

Comment: @COLDSPEED why you dont recommend inplace=True (i thought this save the step of reassigning a variable one more time after an operation eg df.drop(....inplace=True) instead of df=df.drop(....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the variable new a reference to the original object 'df' (i.e.
>   mutable and exposed) or it is now referred to a new instance?

Why don't you just...

```
In [516]: id(df)
Out[516]: 4481803432

In [517]: id(t[1])
Out[517]: 4481803432
```

> I thought tuple (similar to the behavior string) that it always gives
>   you a new object unlike list...

Wrong. The only difference between `tuple`s and `list`s is that the former is immutable. Both would become a container for the same references.

> So I thought if we call a DataFrame in a tuple will create a new
>   object without having the need to do the .copy()

It does not. You will need to explicitly call `.copy()` if you want a copy. Otherwise you're working with the same reference.

> Can I safely say that it is always a good practice to do a copy() to
>   avoid mutation?

Not really, because most of the dataframe mutation methods return a copy of the dataframe. Changes are never made inplace unless you explicitly request it (such as using the `inplace=True` flag).

You should know that setting `inplace=True` does not improve performance because a copy is internally created and then assigned back to the original.