# python tuple immutability issues

Tags: python, immutability

Came across below lines of codes:

```
first_names = ['Fred', 'George', 'Bill']
last_names = ['Smith', 'Jones', 'Williams']
name_tuple = (first_names, last_names)

first_names.append('Igor')
#name_tupple why this output
#(['Fred', 'George', 'Bill', 'Igor'], ['Smith', 'Jones', 'Williams'])
```

- If tuple is immutable why tuple referenced get change on appending new item to list?

i know tuple have reference of list and list is immutable in python.

why dont make tuple a copy of elements that can be constant through out?

Answer (score -1):

You said it: you have a tuple of references to lists.  The references are not changing, only the lists are.  As Henrik Andersson pointed out in comments, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9756028/2715819) explains it very well.