# Printing a new list with existing list

Tags: python, list, sorting, tuples

I would like to take a list like this: ['5', '0 1', '1 2', '1 8', '2 3'] and return a new list made of tuples like this: [(0,[1]),(1,[0,2,8]),(2[1,3]),(3,[2]),(8,[1])]. The first element of each tuple is an integer and the second element is a list of integers it appears next to in the original list. I cannot use dictionaries, sets, deque, bisect module.

```
def create_network(file_name):
    friends = open(file_name).read().splitlines()
    network=[]

    for strings in friends:
        relationship=strings.strip().split(' ')
        if len(relationship)==2:
             a,b=relationship
             a=int(a)
             b=int(b)
             if a>=len(network):
                 network.append((a,[b]))
             else:
                 wow=network[a]
                 wow[1].append(b)
                 network[a]=wow


    return network
```

This is what I have so far. I want it to return:
[(0, [1, 2, 3]), (1, [0, 4, 6, 7, 9]), (2, [0, 3, 6, 8, 9]), (3, [0, 2, 8, 9]), (4, [1, 6, 7, 8]), (5, [9]), (6, [1, 2, 4, 8]), (7, [1, 4, 8]), (8, [2, 3, 4, 6, 7]), (9, [1, 2, 3, 5])] but it is returning 
[(0, [1, 2, 3]), (1, [4, 6, 7, 9]), (2, [3, 6, 8, 9]), (3, [8, 9]), (4, [6, 7, 8]), (5, [9]), (6, [8]), (7, [8])]. I don't know why it isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
from itertools import combinations


def create_network(lst):
    seen = {}

    for e in lst:
        for s, t in combinations(map(int, e.split()), 2):
            seen.setdefault(s, set()).add(t)
            seen.setdefault(t, set()).add(s)

    return [(k, sorted(values)) for k, values in seen.items()]


data = ['5', '0 1', '1 2', '1 8', '2 3']
result = create_network(data)

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[(0, [1]), (1, [0, 2, 8]), (2, [1, 3]), (3, [2]), (8, [1])]
```

The general idea is to create a dictionary where the keys are the integers and the values are a set of integers it appears next
to. The statement `map(int, e.split())` creates an iterable of integers, then using [combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) pick every possible pair 
from the iterable, add each pair to the dictionary and finally return the tuples where the values are sorted.

**UPDATE** *(not using any built-in module)*

```
def combinations(m, lst):
    if m == 0:
        return [[]]
    return [[x] + suffix for i, x in enumerate(lst) for suffix in combinations(m - 1, lst[i + 1:])]


def create_network(lst):
    uniques = []
    for s in lst:
        for e in map(int, s.split()):
            if e not in uniques:
                uniques.append(e)

    result = []
    for number in uniques:
        seen = []
        for e in lst:
            values = list(map(int, e.split()))
            for s, t in combinations(2, values):
                if s == number:
                    if t not in seen:
                        seen.append(t)
                elif t == number:
                    if s not in seen:
                        seen.append(s)
        if seen:
            result.append((number, sorted(seen)))

    return sorted(result)


data = ['5', '0 1', '1 2', '1 8', '2 3']
network = create_network(data)
print(network)
```

**Output**

```
[(0, [1]), (1, [0, 2, 8]), (2, [1, 3]), (3, [2]), (8, [1])]
```

The above code does not use set, dictionary nor any external module. Be warned it can be slow.

Comment: Tuples can’t contain unhashable lists?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention I can't use dictionaries.

Comment: @NChauhan Could you please elaborate? The code above runs in Python 3.5

Comment: @Cam can you use combinations?

Comment: @DanielMesejo I thought tuples couldn’t contain unhashable types i.e lists

Comment: @NChauhan yes they can, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755990/why-can-tuples-contain-mutable-items

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
d = ['5', '0 1', '1 2', '1 8', '2 3']
def find_edges(_d, c):
  return [(a if b == c else b) for a, b in _d if c in [a, b]]

new_d = [[int(c) for c in i.split()] for i in d if len(i) > 1]
_final = []
for i in [h for d in new_d for h in d]:
   if not any(j == i for j, _ in _final):
      _final.append((i, find_edges(new_d, i)))
```

Output:

```
[(0, [1]), (1, [0, 2, 8]), (2, [1, 3]), (8, [1]), (3, [2])]
```