# using .append on tuple and it works although it should give an error.Why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

I know that tuple is an immutable object and we can't change it after it is created,but in my code I should explain why and why not I can do following codes

```
t = (1, 's', [] )
t[2].append(-1)
print(t)
```

and it outputs

```
(1, 's', [-1])
```

So basically I did change the tuple and it did not give out an error
How can I give an explanation to it?

Comment: @python_learner yes it does answer it.Thank you very much

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755990/why-can-tuples-contain-mutable-items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tuple is likely a set of memory addresses where each address is immutable, and when you get a index into the tuple it returns a memory address to the object (In this case python obscures this from your view so you don't have to worry about it) so when you do `.append` on the list as a index in the tuple you change the list and aren't affected by the immutability of the tuple