# Why is a set not taking tuple (where dictionary is an item) as a key?

Tags: python, dictionary, set, tuples, mutable

I understand that set keys are immutable, hence data types like lists are not eligible for being a key in the set. In the example shown below why can a tuple not work as a key if a dictionary is present inside the tuple? Can somebody help me with an explanation?

```
x= (1,{'a':1})
y= (1,2)
print(type(x),type(y))

# piece of code which is not giving me an error is below
set1 = {x,'INDIA'}

# set 2 can be created in similar manner without an error
set2 = {y,'INDIA'}

set2
```

Comment: All the items in a set must be hashable and dictionary aren't (nor are tuples of them).

Answer (score 0):

If it were possible, think of this situation:
`x[1]` is refers to the dict, which is a mutable object.
If elsewhere in you program someone holds a reference to that dict and modifies it, the next time you'll use `x` it will have a "different value" (so e.g., won't belong in the set anymore).

```py
x = (1, {'a':1})
print(x)
x[1]['a'] = 'BANANA'
print(x)
```

Output:

```
(1, {'a': 1})
(1, {'a': 'BANANA'})
```

Comment: x is a tuple, hence immutable. Having a mutable item in it does not make it mutable.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755990/why-can-tuples-contain-mutable-items

Comment: @Yogesh yea that's true, `x[1]` is always the same `x[1]`, changing my wording to simply show why this is a problem if it were allowed.

Answer (score 0):

A `tuple` can only serve as a key if all elements of the `tuple` can serve as a key. A `dict` cannot serve as a key (because it is mutable).

The more technical answer here is that `dict` keys must be hashable, and that `tuple`s are only hashable if their individual elements are hashable.